# Is it possible to integrate Angular.js (Angular 1) and AEM (Adobe Experience Manager 6.2)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, adobe, aem

I cannot include all the things I need an answer to the title, so here is what I concern:

- Must a client side framework/lib be required when developing AEM ? If yes what is the best one fits to AEM and easy for development (Angular.js is just the way that I think it is "enough" good and easy for integration).
- In case of using angular.js, I have some doubts:

  - Which is the most outter App (which is initialized with `ng-app`) and how We load it because AEM component is separated and I can not load most outter in any of them.
  - IMO, most outter `ng-app` will be loaded in the template (which is required by all the components, but it is just in theory (I'm not sure about that) and I do not see any example outhere show me how to load JS,CSS files on TEMPLATE creation (not component creation, just for clearly)
  - Alternative approach, each AEM component will be an separated angular module, and it will bootstraped manually (I'm not sure, too, please help to clarify)

Last but not least, If you have examples (enough complicated, not like hello world) or production project that used this stack (perfect !), please help to let me know, because my biggest concern is "is it possible to do".

Many many thanks in advance !

Comment: https://www.capella.edu/online-degrees Here its used. Not sure what your exact requirement but we can use it as a replacement for jquery and do all stuff.Add ng-app of your main template so all the pages created from it will have access to ng-app and we can add angular code in any component.

Comment: Does your page can be authored by the admin (like dragging in and dropping out any components)?

Comment: The whole center piece is single component which load itself based on Json from backend service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently using angular JS with AEM successfully.

Which is the most outter App (which is initialized with ng-app) and how We load it because AEM component is separated and I can not load most outter in any of them.

**ans**: You can create a renderer component for this purpose and make it as an outer app then add the required clientlibs to it. after that you can use the renderers scope as a normal angular application.

IMO, most outter ng-app will be loaded in the template (which is required by all the components, but it is just in theory (I'm not sure about that) and I do not see any example outhere show me how to load JS,CSS files on TEMPLATE creation (not component creation, just for clearly)

**ans:** Rather than loading it in the template It will pretty easy to add it in the component as a client lib because everything like js / css in AEM we can add it as a client lib

Alternative approach, each AEM component will be an separated angular module, and it will bootstrapped manually (I'm not sure, too, please help to clarify)

**ans:** Yes you can create a component as an angular application and you can bootstrap it seperately

[image: Here is the directory structure for a clientlib]

Comment: Actually, I chose jQuery instead for safety at that moment, I gonna use your solution at the next time with AEM (if any), thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Angular 1.x with AEM 6.x and created SPA (Single Page Application). Also, created AEM Screens App using Angular 1.x.

There could be many ways to do it, but I have followed the following approach :-

> 1. AEM Page template (**body tag**) with **ng-app** and added angular dependency for site (clientlib angular 1.x)
> 2. Define angular module in your site clientlib(JS) say **module.js**, 
>      `example: var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap.tpls','ui.bootstrap.modal']);`
> 3. You can also define state provider for different paths `app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {});`
> 4. Define each component specific module/controller in a specific clientlib(js) file. 
>      `example (html): <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl" />` 
>      `example (client lib(js)) - app.controller('LoginCtrl',
>      function ($scope) {});`